# El uso de «se» en «se llevó los niños a rezar»

Tags: gramática, verbos, pronombres, se

¿Qué significa el *se* en esta frase?

> Siempre didáctico, hizo [Melquíades] una sabia exposición sobre las virtudes diabólicas del cinabrio.  Úrsula no le hizo caso, sino que **se** llevó los niños a rezar

Aquí pienso que este `se` refiere a los niños.

¿Pero no es `se` solo se ultiza cuando  refiere a un objecto indirecto?

¿O es porque aquí tenemos una palabra `los` antes el `niños`, por eso usa `se`?

¿Por eso, la frase `sino que le llevó el niño a rezar` es correcta?

¿O todas esas conjecturas son falsas, y es por otra razón?

Comment: Marvelous quote. I love that book.

Comment: Keep in mind that _se llevó los niños a rezar_ is equivalent to _llevó los niños a rezar_. So I think Martín-Blas has the most specific answer, but all are good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Explicación exhaustiva del uso de *se*](http://mimosa.pntic.mec.es/ajuan3/lengua/usosdese.htm). Yo lo incluiría en en caso *dativo o intensificador del verbo*:

> A veces, el pronombre reflexivo sirve únicamente para intensificar el significado del verbo, en construcciones transitivas o intransitivas.

La frase original debería ser "Ursula no le hizo caso, sino que se llevó **a** los niños a rezar".

En cuanto a la frase alternativa, yo diría que es incorrecta, pero en cualquier caso *suena* horrible.

Comment: Pero segu'n este web_sitio, no hay ese 'a' en el texto.https://archive.org/stream/GarciaMarquezGabrielCienAnosDeSoledad1/garcia-marquez-gabriel-cien-anos-de-soledad1_djvu.txt

Comment: Y si auqí es dativo, que Úrsula ha dado a los niños? La acción de rezar?

Comment: Y además, según el web sitio tuyo. En el columno de Dativo o intensificador del verbo, no encuentro el (se) en el segundo caso, es como΅                       No concordados: la persona del pronombre no coincide con el sujeto:
· ¡No seas embustero!/¡No me seas embustero!

Comment: Mira, no hay se en la frase arriba.

Comment: Ahy, espera, pienso ya puedo ver la llave para abrir esta puerta!

Comment: Aquí este (se) puede referir a Úrsula, para intensificar algo. Así es, que bruto!

Answer (score 3):

Primero, hay que recordar que *se* solo tiene interpretación indirecto si le sigue un pronombre átono directo.  No puede representar los niños, porque si *se* fuese reflexivo con referencia a ellos, el verbo tendría que acordarse con *los niños*, pero está en singular.

Creo que necesitaría algo más de contexto para estar seguro pero...

Para mí, ***les*** llevó **a** los niños a rezar significa más que les provocó a rezar, aunque la mayoría de los hablantes preferirían *los/las llevó a rezar* para tal significado. (soy algo leísta)

El verbo *llevar* tiene muchos usos transitivos, pero no carece de usos pronominales que obligan el uso de del pronombre reflexivo (*se* en tercera persona)

- Yo te llevo a un sitio<sub>* (Te dirijo o te conduzco al sitio aquel)*</sub>
- Yo te me llevo a un sitio<sub>* (Te quito de dónde estés y te llevo al sitio aquel en plan secuestro o para escaparte de algo)*</sub>

Es decir, pone muchísimo énfasis en el acto de tomar la cosa en vez de entregarla o transportarla, tanto que este uso lo define la RAE como

> Quitar algo a alguien, en general con violencia, o furtivamente.

Ya que la primera parte dice que no le hizo caso, se supone que ella recogió a los niños contra la voluntad del / la que representa «le» por lo que está en forma pronominal.

Comment: La frase antes de lo que he mencionado en este cuestion es (Siempre didáctico, (Melquíades) hizo una sabia exposición sobre las virtudes diabólicas del cinabrio).

Comment: Si uso (les llevó a los niños a rezar). Es posible que debo entender que Úrsula ha dado la acción de rezar a los niños?

Comment: Más que las acciones de Úrsula causó que ellos rezasen.  Cuidado con esto porque debe ser objeto *directo*.  La *a* que aparece es la a personal.  *Le* es exclusivamente indirecto para la mayoría de hablantes.

Answer (score 2):

Leí esa parte y definitivamente le falta una *a*.

En esa parte Melquíades rompe un frasco de bibloruro de mercurio, ella le reclama por el olor, Melquíades hace una explicación/juego como acostumbraba y es donde viene la frase.

> Siempre didáctico, hizo [Melquíades] una sabia exposición sobre las virtudes diabólicas del cinabrio. Úrsula no le hizo caso, sino que se llevó los niños a rezar.

Se entiende que por el mal olor ella no querría estar ahí, y mucho menos con los niños, entonces lo más apropiado sería *llevárselos* a otro lugar. Decidió llevarlos a rezar que probablemente sería a la iglesia.

> se llevó ***a*** los niños a rezar.

Es probable que no esté la *a* porque muchas veces las *as* se contraen al hablar:

> ¿Qué vas a hacer hoy?

La *a* desaparece quedando:

> ¿Qué vas hacer hoy?

*Vas a hacer* se contrae, hay dos *as* juntas y éstas tienden a combinarse. Muchas personas jamás se enteran de que debería haber una *a* escrita ahí, sin embargo cuando se habla lentamente ahí si se pronuncia, es decir si yo quiero pronunciar cada palabra si aparece, o al menos debería porque es la combinación:

> Ir a + verbo en infinitivo:
>
> Voy/vas/va/vais/vamos/van a:
>
> - comer
> - hablar
> - caminar
> - hacer
> - hablar

Sí se juntan bastante *llevó* y *a* , pero me parece que sí se escucha claramente la *a*. Es probable que se haya tratado de un error o quiso hacer el diálogo más acorde a la pronunciación real [aunque repito considero que si se escucha la *a*].

> - se llevó *a* los niños a rezar
>
> En el habla rápida la pronunciación quedaría como:
>
> - se llevoá los niños a rezar

Respondiendo a tus preguntas. Cuando dice:

> Se llevó los niños

Quiere decir que ella *llevó* a los niños a algún lugar, se usa se porque los niños son pequeños entonces ellos son manejables y responden a la voluntad de la persona a cargo, por lo tanto ella *se los puede llevar* como si de una cosa se tratase.

> sino que le llevó el niño a rezar

A mi parecer no está mal y se entiende bien pero yo lo diría como:

> sino que le llevó al niño para rezar

Aquí Úrsula está llevando a los niños con una persona en especial, y los está llevando para que recen pero no tiene nada que ver con el significado del principio que es, llevar a los niños fuera a rezar.

Comment: Es curioso que si buscas por Google la frase *se llevó los niños* (un caso en que los niños tienen que ser complemento directo), es de uso frecuente y panhispánico, y en Google N-Grams (de libros publicados) está muy bien registrado.  Siempre por debajo de con la a persona, pero no es un uso marginario.

Comment: Es interesante que lo menciones, la frase como tal "se llevó los niños" aparece desde el siglo XIX pero de todas formas es mucho más común "se llevó a los niños con una diferencia de 2500% aproximadamente.